Are data in the real world "sampled" in the statistical sense?
In machine learning, it is commonly assumed that samples are generated i.i.d. according to some probability distribution. On the importance of the i.i.d. assumption in statistical learning
The fundamental assumption is that there exists some distribution/pdf/cdf/pmf $f_X$ and $f_X$ can be sampled.
$$X \sim f_X(x)$$
My question is simple, which is how does this mathematical assumption model our experience in the real world or applications arising from data science and machine learning.
When we say that samples are sampled from a distribution, what does that mean in the real world?
For example, if I want to do classification between pictures of cats and dogs, I generate my dataset by take out my iphone 16 and taking some pictures of cats and dogs.
I cannot see how this simple action of pressing a button on my iphone is equivalent to a sampling process from some probability distribution.
Can I mathematically describe the action of a camera using a probability distribution $f_X$? No. Can I even dream to write down the probability density function $f_X$ associated with images of cats or dogs? Impossible. The existence of the probability distribution $f_X$ is dubious for all but the most toy/trivial datasets.
So what is the sampling assumption in machine learning trying to model? Why not start with "Suppose we have a dataset of some examples." and omit the sampling assumption.

Perhaps this thread's answers will be clarifying: Who are frequentists?

I cannot see how this simple action of pressing a button on my iphone is equivalent to a sampling process from some probability distribution. Why not? There's some probability distribution on the pixel space of the image, right?

@Dave No. There does not exist a probability distribution on the pixel space of images. Even if it exists, it is unimaginably complex that renders statement such as "sampling" from that distribution irrelevant. It would be the same as saying "walking to Pluto while wearing a space suit".

It depends on what you want the model to be, it's very easy to see how you could recreate the experiment of taking your camera and taking photos and, in the long-run along many trials, you will get a distribution. That's frequentism. It doesn't matter that you can't write down this distribution, it is as real as any other.

@Firebug The assumption in data science/machine learning is that data are generated in an i.i.d. manner from a distribution. But in the real world, data are generated from taking pictures using a camera (or many different cameras). I guess my question here is: is taking a picture using a camera a type of sampling process? If yes, then from which distribution is this sampling process sampling from? How do we mathematically describe that distribution? How do we even know that this distribution exists?

Think about what it would mean in a classification problem for the observations to be $iid$, particularly the “identically distributed” part, and you will see why this $iid$ assumption is not correct.

"The assumption in data science/machine learning is that data are generated in an i.i.d. manner from a distribution." That's not an necessary assumption, it just makes things easier, but it's often unrealistic. "But in the real world, data are generated from taking pictures using a camera (or many different cameras)." Yes, and you can account for their non-independence, for example: for modeling video you are pretty much required to.

"I guess my question here is: is taking a picture using a camera a type of sampling process?" It is. "If yes, then from which distribution is this sampling process sampling from?" The distribution of going out and taking pictures, which can be conditioned on many things such as the environment, the camera, the intention, etc. "How do we mathematically describe that distribution?" This is a framing issue. It might as well not be possible to model it. Does not mean it does not exist. "How do we even know that this distribution exists?" Because we sample from it everytime we take a photo.

@Firebug Thank you. I concede that this distribution is unimaginably difficult to describe, depends on dozens of nebulous variables, and very high dimensional to boot. I concede that this distribution exists. But I guess any statements on sampling is vacuously true. For example, the universe itself sampled from a distribution (I cannot prove that distribution does not exist based on your argument).

@Firebug Also if you know any text/reference that also echoes your view in the comments I would really appreciate it and probably will cite it often whenever I make a statement such as, "suppose these videos are sampled from some distribution". I'm not being sarcastic by the way. Knowing an authoritative reference that describes the probability distribution of everything in this manner would be a huge relief for me.

The literature distinguishes (usefully) between "model uncertainty" and "sampling uncertainty."  That's worth investigating.

HI @ShamisenExpert, I'm not sure I have a good reference for that

Thich Nhat Hanh said that "everything depends on everything else". He is probably right, meaning that in reality nothing is really i.i.d.
Note also that probability can be used with more than one meaning. Particularly there is "epistemic probability", often assumed in Bayesian statistics, not referring to how reality really is, but rather referring to an observer's state of uncertainty.
On the other hand, there is "aleatory probability" or "chance", with frequentist probability as most prominent example, which refers to data generating processes in the world.
The question seems to imply an aleatory/frequentist idea of probability, and this is what I'll assume in this response.
Statistical models are idealisations and tools for thinking, and we shouldn't expect that the world is exactly as what is implied by the model. If I model a certain process as i.i.d., this basically says that temporarily, for the sake of modelling, I treat the process as if it were i.i.d. This particularly implies that any deviation from independence and identity of distributions is ignored in the modelling. My interpretation of this is that it is treated as irrelevant for what I want to achieve.
Whether this is suitable or not depends on whether indeed the i.i.d. model, applied to a specific research aim, will lead to a good and useful result. This may or may not be the case. It depends on how exactly the violation of i.i.d. plays out in the real situation, and also on what the model is used for. For example, if in fact there is a trend over time that is ignored by my model, predictions will not be good because I treat a situation later in time like the situation in which I collected the data, which is misleading. If there is dependence between observations, I may underestimate uncertainty, because my data may show little variation not because indeed there is little variation in the process, but because of dependence, and observations collected much later may be further away from the observations I have than I expect.
On the other hand, a method may work very well in practice even if model assumptions are violated, because the way model assumptions are violated may not be problematic. For example, there may be lots of variation in observations and there may be a good deterministic but complicated explanation why every single observation comes out where it comes out, if we knew everything that has an impact on this observation. But we may be in a situation in which much of this is unobserved, so we can't know and model it, and it may be suitable and lead to satisfactory results to use a model that models the result of all these nonrandom factors as i.i.d. random variation.
The performance of model-based analysis in practice should be monitored and questioned so that we can see and react if something happens that deviates from the model so much that problems in the real situation arise from it. In that case we may make the model more complex by involving for example trends over time and dependence, at least if we have suitable data for doing this.
Statisticians like to control aspects of the data collection such as random sampling, randomisation, double blind studies and the like, in order to make sure that certain issues with the data collection that are known to easily lead to bad consequences cannot happen. But this is not always possible (and probably never perfectly possible; for example even random number generators used for randomisation produce numbers that are not really random), so we should always keep up some awareness for potential issues with what we are doing, and what their consequences may be.
Another thing to keep in mind is that "assumptions" generally refer to the theoretical properties of a method. This means that if an assumption is fulfilled, there will be some desirable theoretical property. It does not mean that the model will automatically be bad if the assumption is not fulfilled. Sometimes it is and sometimes it isn't, see above.
The use of the model assumptions is that we can analyse the behaviour of a method at least in an idealised situation in which we can control the truth. It makes a lot of sense to use methods that at least in such situations perform well; you'd expect good behaviour in such a simple idealised situation as a minimum requirement for a good method. This does not automatically mean that the method will work well in practice, as practice isn't the same. But for sure if a method doesn't work well in a simple idealised situation, there is little hope it'll do a great job in practice.
By the way, I have written about this here.

I've decided to add a more direct answer to this:

Why not start with "Suppose we have a dataset of some examples." and omit the sampling assumption.

In fact this is possible. There are statistical or "data science"  methods that are not explicitly connected to statistical model assumptions, such as nearest neighbour classification and regression, standard hierarchical clustering such as average linkage, or correspondence analysis. Also much development of neural networks wasn't connected to statistical modelling.
But statistical modelling has advantages. I see basically three such advantages.

Quantifying uncertainty is a basic task in statistics and of great real life importance. But uncertainty quantification always needs to rely on an idea about how variation in results could come about, i.e., how data could have been had they not been exactly the same, which requires a model for data generation (the only exception is if an algorithm itself has a random component such as random initialisation, in which case one can explore variation caused by algorithm randomness, but this isn't really a substitute for modelling variation in the data generating process). Note by the way that "nonparametric" approaches to quantify uncertainty such as bootstrap are in fact based on implicit assumptions such as i.i.d. (in its standard form) and taking the empirical distribution of the data as underlying distribution of the data generating process.

One principle to construct a good method for a data analytic problem is to set up an idealised model in which the truth can be controlled, and then to find mathematically (or experimentally) a method for solving the problem optimally (in a well defined sense) assuming the model. This makes sure that the method will work well at least in the assumed idealised situation. One can see this as a very valuable justification that non-model based methods don't have. Very often the result of such reasoning is misrepresented saying that "the model needs to be true for the method to be applied (or at least to work well)". But this is not really the point. In reality all kinds of things can happen and the model will not be fulfilled, but still, we have made sure that the method works well at least in a well interpretable, well defined, idealised situation. That's quite something. As discussed in my other answer, in reality it may or may not work well, but at least we have some more information than just the definition and idea of a method. And in many more complex situations, starting from a model is probably the best/easiest way to arrive at any method that is reasonable.

More generally, statistical models are tools for systematic quality assessment of methods, and this also will lead to better understanding of their characteristics, strengths, and weaknesses. If we want to understand in what kind of situations a method works well and not so well, we can ask, theoretically and (more often) experimentally, how does it perform if data were generated under model A or B or C? This can by the way also be done for methods that were not originally derived from models, see above. Note again that supposedly nonparametric assessment methods such as cross-validation are based on an i.i.d. assumption plus assuming the existing data as representative for the data generating process. There is a certain tendency in machine learning to evaluate methods by looking at their performance in real benchmark data sets, and this makes some sense, but there is a big issue with generalisability and uncertainty quantification (here of the results of quality assessment, which is different from uncertainty quantification of the method's results themselves as mentioned in 1). It is not clear what results on a handful of benchmark data sets say about application of the method to different data. Model-based evaluation has the advantage that (a) it automatically generates variation that can be used for uncertainty quantification, and (b) the modeller can set up various situations for systematically exploring characteristics of the method in question in various well-defined and interpretable settings. This also allows to explore why exactly a method may break down in certain situations and not in others.


The baseline of all this is that it is in fact an advantage for a method to come with model-based theory or experimental exploration. There is a certain tendency to think that it would be better to have non-model based methods because these require no assumptions regarding what is really going on in reality, but in fact the thing is not that model-based methods require assumptions that non-model based methods don't require; rather under the model assumptions there is more knowledge regarding the model-based methods, and this is in principle a good thing (even though occasionally it means that we know that in certain situations deviating from the "assumed" model the method will do badly).
Note that none of these benefits of statistical models requires the models to be true in reality!
Of course supposedly non-model based methods can also be good in certain situations, but in order to have more confidence in this, I'd hope that they are also investigated regarding their behaviour with data generated from statistical models, which can confirm their good performance, in some cases (but by no means always) over a wide range of situations. This is in fact often done in the literature, with wide-ranging "performance guarantees" under general nonparametric models (still requiring something like i.i.d.) backing up some supposedly model-free methods, whereas others may break down for more easily than model-based methods used outside the range of their theoretical "assumptions".

I would throw in a kind of philosophical picture. We can think the real world to be one of many parallel worlds. In statistics  literature you might find it useful to read about the "bootstrap world".

There is a quote from George Box saying $``\textit{All models are wrong...}"$. What is meant is that every model that has been developed and will be in the future is inherently false. Why is that? Because real stochastic phenomena are so complex, that we cannot account for every factor of uncertainty, since for every factor that we identify there is potentially one more that might alter the observed outcome. A nice article is this one $\textit{Science and Statistics
} (1976)$ by George Box.
Now, since we are unable to recreate the observation processes of real stochastic phenomena, we end up developing idealizations of what we believe the observations process must be (so called models). A trivial example, we want to analyse the heights of people in this globe (positive real numbers). The heights can arise from something really complex that I cannot even picture what could be. However, my mortal brain knows that positive real number can be modelled with a Normal distribution (for sake of the example, since yes Normal distribution takes negative values as well). But, what is a Normal distribution? It doesn't grow on the trees, it is a tool that we developed and use to describe stuff, and reality couldn't care less. Hence, even this simple model is wrong.
Let's bring into the picture the i.i.d. notion. I think with certainty no observation process produces i.i.d. samples, but we use it in order to simplify our calculations, it is a necessary evil. Hence, for a real example having created a wrong model, and on top of that having imposed wrong assumption of i.i.d. seems that we go downhill with every step that we make.
Fortunately, some wrong models (wrong in terms of what is the real observation process) can recreate with acceptable accuracy what we have observed (Goodness of Fit, Model Selection etc.). Even though those models are wrong are useful to explain our surrounding stochastic phenomena. Therefore, we try to approximate what is happening in reality and some times with high accuracy.
An example, that I like that pictures this difference between reality and what we actually model is the following, in this case we control what reality is:
Reality:
Behind the scenes we generate some data from a Mixture of Gamma distributions
Our Wrong Model:
We fit a Mixture of Normal distributions
We can still get sensible results from the fit of the Mixture of Normal, however, our model is wrong.
Last, note i.i.d. might be not the most fearsome violation that we impose to our models.
Hope that might help!
